# Give tqdm a hint about task duration to improve initial accuracy

Tags: tqdm

I am using tqdm to track progress when processing 6 large files. Each file is very large and takes about 10 min. During the first 10 min, tqdm is unable to offer an accurate time estimate because it has not collected any data points yet. After the first file is done, the progress report works satisfactorily.

Is there a way to hint tqdm with my own estimate of how long the task will take? For example, something like `tqdm(file_list, hint="10 min")` would have tqdm start with "60 min remaining" rather than "? min remaining". As it actually progresses through the iterable, it would then update this initial estimate accordingly.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a related question: how to make tqdm show the elapsed time for the first task (and maybe also future ones, if possible)?